# after migrate to .net core 2.0 session stop working correctly

Tags: c#, .net, session, asp.net-core

I write my application in .NET 1.0 and after an update it to version 2.0 then, my session stopped working.

My settings in Startup.cs:

```cs
services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
});

...

app.UseSession();
```

I set the session at my controller:

```cs
HttpContext.Session.SetString(SessionKey, data);
```

After that I redirect to my static file containing angular:

```cs
return Redirect($"~/index.html?test={test}");
```

The file is placed in the wwwroot folder.

And when I use angular to get data from my app:

```js
$http.get(baseUrl + "/Configure/Refresh?test=" + test).then(handleSuccess, handleError("Error getting settings")
```

I check the session in my controller action:

```cs
 _logger.LogInformation($"Session: {HttpContext.Session.GetString(SessionKey)}");
```

And it is blank. I don't know why - before the update, it worked correctly.

Comment: Did you check the cookies with developer tools (Network tab)? Do you receive any cookies in the response of the first request? Does the browser send any cookies back in the request to the data method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I discover what was wrong. After update session as default have SameSite set to Lax. Before is was none. I set this value to Strict and all work correctly.

```cs
services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.SameSite = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.Strict;
});
```

Article: https://www.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/2016/04/14/preventing-csrf-with-samesite-cookie-attribute/